# NGINX - Mapping html files to php

Tags: php, html, nginx, mapping, fastcgi

I cannot make nginx read php code embedded in .html files for a specific directory (html/test). I run CentOS 6 and have FastCGI installed. I have tried several configurations, but nothing does the job. My nginx.conf looks like this:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;


    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {

        server_name www.domain.com;
        rewrite ^(.*) http://domain.com$1 permanent;


    } 
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name shop-munk.com *.shop-munk.com;


        location / {
            root   /opt/html;
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /opt/html;
        }


        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           opt/html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

    location ~ \.html$ {
            root           opt/html/test;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.html;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
    }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing and server returned "403 Forbidden" for scripts without .php extension.
Following PHP-FPM configuration fixed the problem:

```
security.limit_extensions = .php .html
```